# xsl retrieve attribute value from list

Tags: xml, xls

I wanted to export an xml to another xml format
i've got this xml format, but i don't know how to retrieve a specific attribute value

```
<customer customer-no="DEV04-00058013">
    <credentials>
        <login>demoxml@yopmail.com</login>
        <password encrypted="true" encryptionScheme="scrypt">$s0$b0401$IsYbtazLWWpFB5YgeN7TXg==$AbbSrO+0531izm83P4UGPNBXt8QiS56V8ARq5IVTfqw=</password>
        <enabled-flag>true</enabled-flag>

    </credentials>
    <profile>
        <salutation/>
        <title/>
        <first-name>Demo</first-name>
        <second-name/>
        <last-name>Xml</last-name>
        <suffix/>
        <company-name/>
        <job-title/>
        <email>demoxml@yopmail.com</email>   
        <gender>1</gender>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="PB_favoriteStore">002</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="CAP_EmailScoring">00002</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="PB_offersViaMail">false</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="PB_offersViaSMS">false</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>
    </profile>
    <note/>
</customer>
```

i wondering how to retrieve PB_favoriteStore value. 
i tried

without success. 
thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you require but the following XPath will select the element where the `attribute-id` is "PB_favoriteStore":

```
//profile/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id='PB_favoriteStore']
```

If you need to select the value in XSL you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//profile/custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id='PB_favoriteStore']"/>
```

Comment: @Dejora if this helped you, please consider accepting this answer